# What do you call someone who keeps asking other people to buy them things when they can just buy it themselves?

Tags: american-english

What do you call someone who asks other people to buy them things when they could just buy it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[moocher](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=moocher&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)*

> One who begs or cadges; a sponge

Also *[schnorrer](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=schnorrer&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)*

> One who habitually takes advantage of the generosity of others; a parasite.

While originally Yiddish, adopted into English and understood in many regions.

*American Heritage*

Comment: I like [*cadger*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cadge), suggested in the moocher definition above.  The person who has no shame in asking...

Answer (score 0):

**to scrounge (verb)**

> to get things, ​especially ​money or ​food, by ​asking for them ​instead of ​buying them or ​working for them:
>
> *Peter never ​buys anything - he just scrounges (off his ​friends).*

**scrounger (noun)**

> (disapproving) 
>   He ​thinks that ​people who ​receive ​welfare ​benefits are scroungers.

— [CAL](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrounge)